# Where can I find invoice templates Magento 1.9.3

Tags: invoice

I'm having trouble finding the right .phtml files that make the invoice layout and design. I can change the upper part of the invoice from system->transactional emails, but the lower part with all the variables etc. I want to change the payment and shipping part of the invoice and also move around the layout a little bit.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

System > Transactional Emails > Add Template

```
Select "New Invoice"
Load Template
Edit as desired
Do the same for guest invoice template as well (if appropriate).
```

System > Configuration > Sales Emails

```
Set the templates you've just created as the templates to use for these emails.
```